# Make easely a sub array from an array

Tags: c++, arrays, c, operators

Check this c/c++ code, but just pay atention to the use of "&" operator and the array operations into the function. Its ok to pass an array like that?, will be any invalid access problem or something like that?. The teacher wanted us for using low level arrays in c++, also i want to know if works in c.´

```
#include <cstdio>

int imprimirSubArreglo(int* dirElemInicial, int n) {
  int numero = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    // cout<<dirElemInicial[i]<<" ";
    printf("%d ", dirElemInicial[i]);
  }

  // cout<<endl;
  printf("\n");

  return numero;
}

int main() {

  int arreglo[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
  int retorno = imprimirSubArreglo(&arreglo[2], 3);

return 0;
}
```

I think it works, but i suspect that can be an invalid access, because an array is taking as its first address the third address of other array of an upper function.

Comment: I want to know that for both c and c++

Comment: In C++ you should be using `std::array` or `std::vector` instead of low level C style arrays, and `std::span`

Comment: Tactical note: C++'s `std::endl` is both a newline and a stream flush, and that flush can be extremely expensive. If you don't need an explicit flush to force the data buffered in the stream out to the underlying media, prefer to just send a newline character.

Comment: I know is better to not use low level c arrays, but the teacher request us to use it in this case

Comment: `<cstdio>` is not guaranteed to place `printf` in the global namespace. To make this code standard-conforming (in practice: portable) you can use a `using` declaration, or just include `<stdio.h>` instead.

Answer (score 3):

It is fine. `int imprimirSubArreglo(int* dirElemInicial, int n)` declares the routine to have a pointer passed to it, not an array. (Even if it were declared to have an array passed to it, such a declaration is automatically adjusted to be a pointer.)

`&arreglo[2]` is a pointer to an `int`, as the parameter requires. The result of the call is that `dirElemInicial` points to an `int`, that being the int `arreglo[2]`.

Further, `dirElemInicial[i]` takes that pointer, adjusts it by `i` `int` objects, and accesses the `int` that is at the calculated location. So `dirElemInicial[0]`, `dirElemInicial[1]`, and `dirElemInicial[2]` access `arreglo[2]`, `arreglo[3]`, and `arreglo[4]`.

You can even use `dirElemInicial[-1]` and `dirElemInicial[-2]` to access `arreglo[1]` and `arreglo[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

Looks fine, the use of the "&" operator to pass a subarray to a function is a common practice in C/C++. When you pass the address of the third element (&arreglo[2]) along with the size of the subarray (3 in this case) to the imprimirSubArreglo function, you are essentially passing a pointer to the beginning of the subarray.

the output of `imprimirSubArreglo` is going to be **2 3 4**